# Need specific summaries in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table invoiceline, with a numeric field discounttype. 
These are numbers from 1 to 10.
Another relevant field is orderquantity
My report now should show two figures:
Figure one: A sum of all ordered items (Qty) where discounttype is one of [1,2,3,5,8,9].
And another sum off all ordered items where discounttype is in [2,3,5].
How to proceed?

If I use the first in the where clause and then group by discounttype, I get results for each, and no combined summaries.

I work with Crystal Reports 2011

Answer (score 0):

create two sub reports and place in report header.

In first sub report `Record selection formula` write

```
Discounttype in [2,3,5]
```

In second sub report `record selection formula` write

```
discounttype in [1,2,3,5,8,9]
```

In design of both sub reports perform summary operations as required.